# Complex power series centered at w

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

For any $w \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$, find a power series for 
                $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$$

centred at $w$ and give the radius of convergence. Further, find a power series for $f$ which converges in a neighbourhood of infinity.

I have a few questions. I can rewrite my series

$$f(z)=\frac{-1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}=\frac{-1}{z}\sum\frac{1}{z^n}$$

Is this series still centered about 0? As regards the question above my thought is to try something of the form

$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1}{1-w-(z-w)}=\frac{1}{1-w}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-w}{1-w}}=\sum\frac{(z-w)^n}{(1-w)^{n+1}}$$

Which is now centered about $w$?

Comment: Your first series is incorrect, you should have $z^n$, not the reciprocal. Your latter formula looks correct. Substituting $w=0$ will give the desired series about $z=0$.

Comment: My first series is correct I think. Because we have $\frac{1}{1-x}$ where $x=\frac{1}{z}$

Comment: Power series are in terms of $z^k$ not ${1 \over z^k}$. Your Laurent expansion is valid in $|z|>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:Your method is correct for  $\dfrac{|z-w|}{|1-w|}<1$ .
For the series

$f(z)=\frac{-1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}=\frac{-1}{z}\sum\frac{1}{z^n}$
note that it is valid in the anulus $|z|>1$.

Comment: So we can consider it centered around in infinity on the compactification of the complex plane?
Furthermore, $|z-w|<|1-w|$ would be centered around $w$ then, correct?

Comment: Yes your claims sre correct :)